# Provide minimum padding between UITextField and software keyboard ios

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I am using UITextField hosted inside UIScrollView and using keyboard notification to adjust content size, right now when scrollview scrolls to textfield the padding between keyboard and textfield is too small. Is there anyway I can customise padding??

Comment: Please show code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Some screenshot of the issue can also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) for automatically provide padding and without any trouble of scrollView with single Line of code. You can install it via `CocoaPods` or `Manually`.

Answer (score 1):

Set the contentInset of the UIScrollView

```
scrollView.contentInset = .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 15, right: 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

add bottom constraint outlet of Scroll View( this must be the bottom constraint of last textfield from bottom).
and in that view controller add the following line of code.

```
    fileprivate func addKeyBoardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
    
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
//                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
                self.scrollViewBottomAnchor.constant = -keyboardSize.height
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.scrollViewBottomAnchor.constant = 0
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
    }
```